# Diff Algorithm for Legislation

Tags: text, diff, text-processing

As part of an ambitious project, I am attempting to better understand the legislative text that is written into bills introduced in the U.S. Congress.  I have electronic versions of recent bills, and am attempting to implement an algorithm that would compare a bill with prior bills, looking for similarities.  The hypothesis is that many bills that fail end up getting co-opted into other bills.

Obviously, this is a large task.  Many questions exist regarding difference engines, but my issue is slightly different.  Many times bills are introduced that package several ideas together.  So the difference engine would need to compare portions of bills, not the entire bills.

Any recommendations on difference algorithms or a method to go about doing this?  I have access to serious computational power, but do keep in mind that I will be using a dataset of about 100,000 bills.

Comment: You may want to check out Lucene/SOLR fulltext search engines, there may be some plugins that do what you are looking for.

Comment: Did anything ever come of this? It sounds very interesting.

Comment: Hopefully, this will become a journal article sooner or later!  It's being actively studied at my University.  I'll send you a link if (when) it gets published.  Longest common subsequence is the approach that we'd like to take, but it is proving computationally infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Simian - Similarity Analyser](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/). It works for plain text as well as code.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting idea.  I would start by looking into [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithms, and see about adapting them to (1) report *any* sequence over some threshold, say, 20 words, and (2) see if you can get them to handle a bit of fuzziness, in case a word or two gets changed.  I'd suggest looking at the diff code to start.